# problems with bar counting in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to ask for help as i cant figure this out. I am trying to build indicator that you can see bellow, idea is simple, 2 moving averages and they cross at some point. i want to implement bar counting to it so after price action(ma3 or ma4 crosses ma2 counter starts in favour of short or long position). my problem is with "entrylong/entryshort" script part as i think counter does not work properly, i can see it counts in plot but when i set up plot for "entrylong/entryshort" it does not print anything. Any corrections/ideas would be really appreciated. Thanks
You can see code in first comment
P.S Moving averages ma1 and ma2 are changed as i want to keep them as secret :D

//@version=5

```
//VC
indicator('VC 1.0', overlay=true)

// Define the length and source for the first moving average
len = 10
src = close
ma1 = ta.ema(src, len)

// Define the length and source for the second moving average
len1 = 20
src1 = close
ma2 = ta.ema(src1, len1)

// Define the length and source for the third moving average
len2 = 1
src2 = high
ma3 = ta.ema(src2, len2)

// Define the length and source for the fourth moving average
len3 = 1
src3 = low
ma4 = ta.ema(src3, len3)

// Plot the two moving averages
plot1 = plot(ma1, color=color.green)
plot2 = plot(ma2, color=color.red)

// Fill the area between the two moving averages
up = ma1 > ma2
down = ma1 < ma2
cross = ma3 > ma1 and ma3 > ma2
cross1 = ma4 < ma2 and ma4 < ma1
pullbackshort = ma3 > ma1 and ma3 <= ma2
pullbacklong = ma4 < ma1 and ma4 >= ma2
crosslong = ma3 > ma2
crossshort = ma4 < ma2

mycolor1 = up ? color.green : down and not cross ? color.red : color.rgb(255, 222, 59)
mycolor2 = down ? color.red : up and not cross1 ? color.green : color.rgb(115, 55, 6)
fill(plot1, plot2, color=mycolor1, transp=70)
fill(plot1, plot2, color=mycolor2, transp=70)

// Counter for counting bars

counter = 0
counter := nz(counter[1]) + (ma4 > ma2 ? 1 : 0)
counter := ma4 < ma2 ? 0 : counter
plot(counter, color=color.rgb(137, 230, 140), show_last = 1)

counter1 = 0
counter1 := nz(counter1[1]) + (ma3 < ma2 ? 1 : 0)
counter1 := ma3 > ma2 ? 0 : counter1
plot(counter1,color=color.rgb(237, 143, 143), show_last = 1)

// entries
entrylong = counter >= 5 and ma3 == ma2
entryshort = counter >= 5 and ma4 == ma2
```

Comment: Please don't add your code in the comments section. Instead, edit your question and add the information there.

Comment: sorry, stand corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counters work fine, but the `entrylong` and `entrylong` variables also compare if `ma3` or `ma4` is equal to `ma2`, which may rarely or not happen at all since you are comparing 16-precision floating point numbers. Modify the comparisons to equal & lower/higher and introduce any output to spot the result on the chart:

```
// entries
entrylong = counter >= 5 and ma3 >= ma2
entryshort = counter1 >= 5 and ma4 <= ma2

bgcolor(entrylong ? color.green : na)
bgcolor(entryshort ? color.red : na)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i think i got that i wanted, cant catch equal(=) moment but < or > will be enough.

`entrylong = counter >= 5 and ma3 >= ma2 and ma4 <= ma1
entryshort = counter1 >= 5 and ma4 <= ma2 and ma3 >= ma1`

added it like that, looks like my issue is solved.

Comment: In that case, you can marked the answer as "accepted" ;)